# How to join two different dataframe whit different index

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, spyder

Good morning, I want to join two different DataFrame, but they have different index (As you can see in the picture below). Infact, the first is the result of a train_test_split and the second is an array converted into a DataFrame. The first (`new_features`) is a DataFrame 1700x21 and the second (`y_test_pred_new`) is a DataFrame 1700x1. How can I add the second one (1700x1) to the first DataFrame without pay attention to the index? So Simply taking the 1700x1 and add it as the 22° columns in `new_features`.

```
new_features = pd.concat([X_test3, features_post_test], axis = 1)
y_test_pred_new = pd.DataFrame(y_test_pred,columns = ['Soot_EO_pred'])
```

I tried to do in this way but it doesn't work.

```
new_dataset = pd.concat([new_features, y_test_pred_new], axis= 1)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use append instead of concat, but you have to rest the index of the big dataframe

Comment: I know that I can use .append() if I have to append rows of other to the end of caller

Comment: And why didn't you reset the index ?

Comment: Who can I reset the index?

Comment: ```df = df.reset_index(drop=True)``` or
```df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)```